# How to set virtualenv to another directory?

Tags: virtualenv, virtualenvwrapper

I had a problem come up when I was forced to change my project directory name.

First Virtualenvwrapper didn't see my projects, so I changed the environment variable of WORKON_HOME to the new project directory. I could then activate my envs. But now when my project is doing anything, it thinks it's in the old directory, not the new one. I can't figure out how to change this. I've looked in the [reference material](http://virtualenvwrapper.readthedocs.org/en/latest/command_ref.html), and looked for the place that actually points to where the projects are, but I had no luck with either. Please help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It sounds like you want to set an already-created virtual environment to a directory that contains your project. One way that I am familiar with to do the following, based on the virtualenvwrapper documentation.

1. Activate your desired virtual env 

   `workon myvirtualenv`
2. Change your directory to your desired project directory
   `$ cd my/project/dir`
3. Set your virtualenv project to the current directory
   `$ setvirtualenvproject`

The default is to use the current directory. The full syntax is:

`$ setvirtualenvproject [virtualenv_path project_path]`

I hope this helps!